# Cannot send datetime via SMTPLIB Python

Tags: python, string, datetime, smtplib

I am trying to make a program that'd email me the date and time whenever it is run.
I am using smtlib and verified it already using some string as message and it is working fine. But whenever I add datetime variable and convert it to string it sends an empty email.

```
import smtplib
import datetime

b=datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now())

print b

svr = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
svr.starttls()
svr.login("******@*****", "*********") 

msg = str(b)


svr.sendmail("******@*****", "******@*****", msg)
print ("Terminate")

svr.quit()
```

Comment: No still a blank message. I want only the time to be sent so used b=datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now())

Comment: The msg must contain headers, blank line and the message body.

Answer (score 1):

You should add headers to your `msg` :

```
headers  = "From: From Person \r\n"
headers += "To: To Person \r\n"
headers += "Subject: \r\n"
headers += "\r\n"
msg = headers + msg
```

Comment: IMHO, this fixes the problem. Of course valid mail addresses must be supplied. RFC2822 states that the header lines should be CRLF terminated, i.e. with `\r\n`

Comment: In theory yes , but it works .  And you are right about the `\r\n` , i will update my post .

Answer (score -2):

This is kinda messy but it works, what I have have done is but `b` in a list called `c` and sent the list instead, unfortunately I have no idea why what you where doing doesn't work... Here's the code:

```
import smtplib
import datetime
b = datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now())
c = []
c.insert(0, b)
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login("***********", "***********")

msg = '' + str(c) + ''
server.sendmail("**********", "*********", msg)
server.quit()
raise SystemExit
```

Comment: For some reason I cannot send special characters like : ; etc via smtplib.

Comment: Ok, did putting it it in a list work(not for the special characters but for the original question) If it did please up vote